# Static Value in Google Sheets Array

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to create an array of values from a google sheet. I want to also return a static value.
My formula looks like this at the moment

```
={A2:A5,$A$1,M2:M5}
```

I want it to return something like:

```
Person 1 Blue 5

Person 2 Blue 10

Person 3 Blue 15

Person 4 Blue 10

Person 5 Blue 7
```

Comment: do you need to use this within a Google Sheet or do you need to export this to an application?

Comment: @IncrediblePony I want to keep it in Google Sheets

Comment: I have edited the rights in the sheet so you can edit it @Ilan Buchbinder

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I have now updated the link below in the old answer to match what I think you are looking for. I have made three seperate sheets for you to look at and click around in at the bottom of the linked sheet.

I have used data validation to make some dropdowns for the teams. I have made a list of players where you can add and remove as much as you like (this may be flawed, tell me if you find an error and I'll look into it) - from there I use the data I fetched from the two sheets to make a total calculation with the built in `SUMIF` function. Hope this helps.

**OLD ANSWER**

Right - so I'm not quite sure what you need, but I found an example of what you may be looking for:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hNQ_9c-ZTvoOu1Sd3egjHXsjeITFod88na0OEaBaF54/edit?usp=sharing

[image: Subject context menu]

[image: Sheets Datavalidation modal]

So when you look down at the bottom you can see another sheet that contains some static values. If you rightclick on any of the `Subjects` in the sheet `Assignments` and choose `Data Validation` as shown on the first image you will get the screen on the second image. Here you can see how the data som the sheet `Subjects` is referenced in the sheet `Assignments`

You can also rightclick one of the `Status` column values in the `Assignment` sheet to see how you can create a static list in the `Data Validation` context menu. Hope this answers the question. Either that or please provide more info for me to be able to decipher the question correctly ;)

Comment: Thanks, It's not exactly what I was looking for. I changed the formula. Hopefully it makes it more clear what I am looking for.

Comment: would it be possible for you to send a link to the sheet with view access so I can check it out? Or some kind of example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GMOCJ1rRaahn1ByPy0bLth8sp5uBIcfRkb7sOBBZoPg/edit?usp=sharing

Here is kind of what I am looking for. You can see two sets of Data I have, and the desired outcome below.

Comment: Sorry. I realised my original sheet wasn't really showing what I'm looking for. In the same document, please look at sheet 2. I have this data in a much larger scale. I would like to essentially have ={A2:A3,$A$1,B2:B3} but obviously this doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(A2:B<>"", A1:B1&" "&A2:B, )),,999^99)))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$A$1` is the constant you want repeated 4 times, you could do it like this but it's not pretty:

```
={A2:A5,{$A$1;$A$1;$A$1;$A$1},M2:M5}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can easily work by using ARRAYFORMULA in combination with the defined array's

`={A2:A6,B2:B6, ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A6), , $A$1))}`

[See result in Google sheets with formula above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbueR.png)